# Combinations for each column in list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, combinations, lapply

I have a list of dataframes, each with two columns. Columns have the same class and name in each dataframe and generally only differ in number of rows, e.g.,

```
lst = list(data.frame(n=1:3,
                          l=letters[seq(1:3)]),
            data.frame(n=1:5,
                          l=letters[seq(1:5)]),
            data.frame(n=1:8,
                          l=letters[seq(1:8)]))
```

I'm trying to create a new list of dataframes containing all possible pairwise combinations of values within each column (not between columns), but I haven't been able to get it right.

This code gives me the desired output for a single column, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to all columns in all dataframes in the list using either lapply or for loops, though I'm sure there must be something I'm missing.

```
library(gtools)
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(combinations(nrow(lst[[1]]), 2, v=lst[[1]]$n, set=T, repeats.allowed=F)) %>%
  transmute(x = paste(V1, V2, sep=","))
```

I'd really appreciate any tips!

Comment: please show the packages used

Comment: combinations is from gtools, otherwise just base and tidyverse

Comment: Do you need `map(lst, ~ .x %>% summarise_all(~ list(combinations(n(),  2, v = ., set  = TRUE,  repeats.allowed = FALSE))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` and then with `summarise_all` apply the `combinations`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(gtools)
library(stringr)
map(lst, ~ .x %>% 
      mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
      summarise_all(~ list(combinations(n(),  2, v = .,
          set  = TRUE,  repeats.allowed = FALSE) %>% 
          as_tibble %>%
          transmute(x = reduce(., str_c,  sep=", ")))) %>% 
      unnest(everything(), names_repair = 'unique') %>% 
      rename_all( ~ str_remove(., "\\.+")))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x1    x2   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1, 2  a, b 
#2 1, 3  a, c 
#3 2, 3  b, c 

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   x1    x2   
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 1, 2  a, b 
# 2 1, 3  a, c 
# 3 1, 4  a, d 
# 4 1, 5  a, e 
# 5 2, 3  b, c 
# 6 2, 4  b, d 
# 7 2, 5  b, e 
# 8 3, 4  c, d 
# 9 3, 5  c, e 
#10 4, 5  d, e 

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 28 x 2
#   x1    x2   
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 1, 2  a, b 
# 2 1, 3  a, c 
# 3 1, 4  a, d 
# 4 1, 5  a, e 
# 5 1, 6  a, f 
# 6 1, 7  a, g 
# 7 1, 8  a, h 
# 8 2, 3  b, c 
# 9 2, 4  b, d 
#10 2, 5  b, e 
# … with 18 more rows
```

---

Or another option is with `crossing` and then remove the mirror rows and the rows where two columns are same with `filter`

```
map(lst, ~ 
       map(.x %>%
               mutate_if(is.factor, as.character),
               ~ crossing(x1 = .x, x2 = .x) %>% 
                   filter(x1 != x2)  %>% 
                   filter(!duplicated(cbind(pmin(x1, x2), pmax(x1, x2)))) %>%
                   transmute(x = reduce(., str_c, sep=", "))) %>% 
               bind_cols %>% 
               rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.+")))
```

Comment: Seems like the right track, but something's wonky here. Combination output for [[1]] is showing the number column is mixing with the letter column, which shouldn't happen, That is, 1,2 and a,b are okay, but 1,b is not.

Comment: Still happening:
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x1    x2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 1, 2  1, b 
2 1, 3  1, c 
3 2, 3  b, c

Comment: @quepur sorry, you had factor column. just a scec

Comment: @quepur please check now

Answer (score -1):

try using expand.grid(). Imagine that a, b and c are lists. If you use the function, it will create all the possible combinations